How much noise comes from flex duct vs rigid duct?
My HVAC contractor installed my new furnace and ducting with flexible ducts. The cold air return vents are super loud and I'm wondering if I replaced the flex with rigid, would the system be quieter. The sound is like rushing wind, could it be the register grates? I know my contractor was trying to get the job done quickly and cheaply; I'm just wondering if it is worth my time and money to swap the ducts to hopefully lower the volume.
Pictures added for clarity. The foreground duct is a soft curve but the distant duct makes a couple 90° bends to exit the floor and run above the main beam.

Helped my son move into a new home in Virginia. The AC noise was alarming compared to the sound I get in my condo in Fla.  His ducting is all rigid and mine is all insulated flex.  I think there is a better chance of you taming the sounds by replacing the current flex duct with larger flex.  Same volume lower velocity.


How much noise comes from flex duct vs rigid duct?

depends on the cfm and pressure
however, generally, a rigid duct is noisier than a flexible duct.  A rigid [metal] duct will simply transfer noise inside and along the length of it to an extent far greater than a flexible duct will, especially an insulated flex duct that are used for AC.
however, if you do a slop job, not necessarily your pic, and let a flex duct hang and then for various operating conditions it's flapping around making noise... well...
but, if it is air noise in the duct (rigid or flex) and it is too noisy specifically from the air moving within, then either the duct inner diameter [area] is too small for the amount of air that needs to move through it or the blower is moving air too fast for the given duct size.  There's tables simplifying all these calculations to basic rules of thumb for cfm, static pressure, duct area and length.

Usually they recommend the opposite:  replace rigid duct with flexible to reduce noise.  More generally, rigid materials promote echo.  Flexible materials absorb sound.
Pictures might allow people to give better recommendations.  I'm wondering if it might be possible to change the path of the return to muffle noise without significantly reducing airflow.  Direction changes reduce sound more than airflow.  It's possible that the flexible duct is straighter than it needs to be.
You also might consider how to describe the sound.  Is it the sound of air blowing?  Ductwork rattling?  Fan turning?  Coolant pumping?  Each of those has slightly different solutions.

Really?  I would think a smoother duct would be quieter.  Rough surfaces increase tubulence, and thus, noise.  The link you post says to use rubber ducts.

@Huesmann, I think the noise is transferred from the fan not the rush of the air.  The rigid ducts of metal act like a drum and vibrate creating noise.  Tap on a metal duct and you hear it all through the house. Do the same to a flex duct, especially an insulated duct and you will hear nothing.

@RMDman I guess it depends what the noise you're talking about is—resonance, or turbulence.

Thanks for the feedback. I'm guessing my noise may be due to the turbulence caused by the register grate. I'll pull the grates and run it open for a minute and see what difference that makes.
